# Parallelize a list consolidation in Python

Tags: python, list, parallel-processing

I have a sorted list of "box definitions" that I would like to consolidate. The list looks something like:

```
big_list = [\
# ...
# ...
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 65],\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 60],\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 55],\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 52],\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 23],\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 17],\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 0],\
[5, 8, 9, 6, 9, 10, 90],\
[5, 8, 9, 6, 9, 10, 84],\
[5, 8, 9, 6, 9, 10, 32],\
[5, 8, 9, 6, 9, 10, 0],\
# ...
# ...
[750, 800, 900, 751, 801, 901, 97],\
[750, 800, 900, 751, 801, 901, 24],\
[750, 800, 900, 751, 801, 901, 17],\
[750, 800, 900, 751, 801, 901, 16],\
[750, 800, 900, 751, 801, 901, 0]\
# ...
# ...
]
```

Where the box "format" is: [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, attribute], and we can assume dx=1, dy=1, dz=1

Also, we can assume the list has already been sorted by something like:

```
big_list=sorted(big_list, key=lambda n:n[6], reverse=True)
big_list=sorted(big_list, key=lambda n:n[2])
big_list=sorted(big_list, key=lambda n:n[1])
big_list=sorted(big_list, key=lambda n:n[0])
```

The list may be several millions of items long, and I would like to reduce the list so that any discrete "box" only gets the highest "attribute"...so something in this case like:

```
reduced_big_list = [\
[3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 65],\
[5, 8, 9, 6, 9, 10, 90],\
[750, 800, 900, 751, 801, 901, 97]\
]
```

The method I am currently using on this list is something like:

```
i = 0

while i < len(big_list)-1:
     if big_list[i][0]==big_list[i+1][0]\
     and big_list[i][1]==big_list[i+1][1]\
     and big_list[i][2]==big_list[i+1][2] \
     and big_list[i][6] >= big_list[i+1][6]:
          del big_list[i+1]
     else:
          i=i+1
```

The problem is that when the list is "long" (10 million+ "boxes"), the process is very, very slow.

Is there a clever way to parallelize this list "decimation" process or perhaps quicken this process?

Comment: unrelated hint: line continuation characters are not needed when you're splitting lists across multiple lines.  The parser will notice that a bracketed expression hasn't finished and continue parsing on the next line, even in the absence of a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowness is the call to `del`, which moves the items of the *complete* tail of the list by one step.  In your case, simply don't use `del`.  Make instead a new list, starting from an empty list and `append`ing the items that you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is slow is that each time you `del` a line takes a linear amount of time, making the total process O(n^2).

If instead of deleting lines from the original list, you append the lines you want to keep into a new list, it should be much faster.

But there are other, possibly more Pythonic, ways to perform the same thing. For example, using `itertools.groupby` (assuming the list is sorted as you specified):

```
from itertools import groupby
new_list = [next(group) for val,group in groupby(big_list, key=lambda x: x[:3])]
```

This will group the list items by the first 3 elements, and return a list of the first item in each group.

Comment: Hmmph.  I wrote `[next(g) for k,g in groupby(m, key=lambda x: x[:3])]`, but I don't suppose that's enough to justify a separate answer. :^)  You might want to emphasize that this approach requires that the sorting already be done.

Comment: @DSM: Yeah, I was just editing my answer to make the same change. And the question states that the list is sorted already, but I'll specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean `and` evaluates the left expression first. It only evaluates the right hand expression if the first one is true. Since you've sorted your list, the adjacent elements are maybe more likely to have identical 0th elements than later elements. Try

```
i = 0

while i < len(big_list)-1:
    if big_list[i][2]==big_list[i+1][2]\
    and big_list[i][1]==big_list[i+1][1]\
    and big_list[i][0]==big_list[i+1][0]\
    and big_list[i][6] >= big_list[i+1][6]:
        del big_list[i+1]
    else:
        i=i+1
```

Comment: This is also a good optimization technique for OP's original strategy however del should still be removed

Comment: Since most lines in the example need to be deleted, this will not help (all the boolean conditions will need to be evaluated, no mattter in which order). And it still leaves the O(n^2) runtime.